# Abandoned calls metrics seem too high

Tags: twilio-twiml

Recently we implemented a scheduled callback for our users, and it seemed to coincide with an increase in the abandoned calls metric.
As of now, right after we schedule a callback, we take the call out of the queue and then hang up.
So, the question is :
If a call is taken out of a queue, i.e.: by using , does it count as an abandoned call on the metrics?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming as defined in the [help]

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

> Abandoned conversations may occur because the customer hung up or disconnected due to technical issues (for example, a lost signal while calling from a mobile device). Abandons can happen either in a queue that a customer enters from an IVR or during a transfer to another queue. Abandoned conversations do not include calls disconnected at any point during the IVR flow.

If you are hanging up the call as part of the process of setting up your callback, you should be ok, though it's hard to tell without an example of your code. It's possible that, if you have confirmed to the user that they will get a callback that they are able to hangup before your code hangs them up and that might cause an increase. You might want to check the [Abandoned Phase](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/end-user-guide/insights/abandoned-conversations#abandoned-phase) to see where these abandonments are happening. If you are getting an increase in the Callback Request phase, you might be fine with that and just want to exclude the Abandoned value of Follow-Up when checking these metrics.